# How can I provide a default value for building an ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I provide a default value to an ActiveRecord association?

For example, I have an application where `Attachment` is a polymorphic model, used to store binary data for any other model. It has a `mime_type` field.

For some associations, the `mime_type` is obvious. Eg,

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :pdf, # clearly this will be application/pdf
    class_name: "Attachment",
    as: :attached_to,
    dependent: :destroy

end
```

It's repetitive to say `invoice.build_pdf(mime_type: "application/pdf")`. That should be the default `mime_type` any time I do `invoice.build_pdf` (or `.create_pdf!`, etc).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

### Use a scope block on the association

One way to do this add a scope to the association.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :pdf,
    -> { where(mime_type: "application/pdf") }, # here
    class_name: "Attachment",
    as: :attached_to,
    dependent: :destroy

end
```

This will be used both when querying and when building.